# Focus is coming on validate datepicker field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Focus is coming on validate datepicker field in jquery and it showing me opening calendar. I want only validate message not popup of datepicker.

Comment: no one here answer any question on wild guess, please post related code.

Comment: I can't understand what is exactly the problem. Can you rewrite your sentence?

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("endDate", function(value, element) {
          var startDate = $('#txt_reg_form').val();
          return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value) || value == "";
      }, "To date should be greater then From date");

Comment: @AmitGoyal comment is not place for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack from your method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("endDate", function(value, element) { 

        var startDate = $('#txt_reg_form').val(), 
        ret = Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value) || value == ""; 

        if(!ret){ /*IF NOT VALID DATE*/

            /*TRY DISABLING DATEPICKER FOR A MOMENT*/
            $("#txt_reg_form").datepicker('disable');

            /*SET TIMEOUT TO ENABLE IT AFTER 1 SECOND*/
            setTimeout(function(){
                   $("#txt_reg_form").datepicker('enable');
               }, 1000);
        }
        return ret;
   }
    , "To date should be greater then From date"
);
```

<strike>If a `datepicker` is associated with a field, it will popup calender on focusing on the field. You can change the default behaviour of showing popup on `focus` to show it on clicking button/icon by following code:</strike>

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for wonder full ans but as per requirement i can not use this there is option of clicking on textbox

Comment: can you disable focusing on invalid elements using `focusInvalid` option?

Comment: yes but i am using $.validator.addMethod("endDate", function(value, element)  how can i use in this.

Comment: it is inside your validation function itself. we are storing validation result in `ret` variable. if it is false, disable `datepicker` set timeout to enale it after 1 second and return the validation result (`ret`).

Comment: When i click again on button validation msg appear and disappear again.